# Элемент с горизонатальной прокруткой содержимого в балуне (галлерея с фото)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, прокрутка

Имеем примерной такой код добавления метки с кастомным балуном на карту:

```
const org = {
    name: 'Автосервис на Набережной',
    about: '<div class="org_about"><div class="gallery"><img src="1.jpg" /><img src="2.jpg" /><img src="3.jpg" /><div>...</div>',
    color: 'islands#blueCircleDotIcon'
}

const CompanyBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="fg-ymap-balloon">html code</div>',
    {
        // all the methods
    }
)

const options = {
    balloonLayout: CompanyBalloonLayout,
    balloonContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass( org.about ),
    balloonInteractivityModel: 'default#layer',
    preset: org.color
};

let squarePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    coords, {
        hintContent: org.name,
        balloonContentHeader: org.name,
    }, options
);
```

Вот так выглядит балун:

[image: Кастомный балун на Яндекс Карте]

Как видите, в балуне есть элемент с картинками в горизонтальном ряду. В нормальных условиях, чтобы просмотреть картинки, нужно прокручивать содержимое элемента по горизонтали. Но с опцией `balloonInteractivityModel: 'default#layer'`
карта забирает событие прокрутки и вместо прокручивания картинок перемещается карта. Возможно ли сделать часть балуна не передающей события на карту? Поскольку также нужно оставить, чтобы остальной балун, кроме части с картинками, позволял себя "хватать" и прокручивать карту.

Comment: В самом API такой возможности нет.

Comment: Жаль. Но кажется не сложно добавить функцию ограничения области балуна, где карта не перехватывает события.

Comment: Используемая вами версия API 2.1 более не развивается. Потому предлагаемых вами изменений там ждать не стоит. Основная версия сейчас 3.0. Возможности её ещё немного отстают от 2.1, но мы работаем над улучшением сервиса.